# Canon MF6530: Persistent paper jam. Took video in the tray. No error code

Tags: printing, printer, hardware-failure, repair

The display says "Paper Jam / Open Left Cover" without any code. I don't think the jam is real.

I put a camera inside the paper tray and took a [video](https://www.reddit.com/r/printers/comments/t7ppjm/canon_mf6530_persistent_paper_jam_took_video_in/).

In the video, I see the following things.

1. At 0:03, the cassette pickup roller (CPR) would push the top paper forward.
2. At 0:04, the CPR would push that top paper once more. After that, the top paper completely goes in.
3. At 0:06, the CPR would push the 2nd paper.
4. Then the printer says it gets a paper jam.

The top of the 2nd piece of paper is right at the end of the registration roller. The paper doesn't go a bit beyond the registration roller. After I open the left cover, I can't just pull that single piece of paper out. I have to manually roll the roller to get the 2nd paper out.

Here is a [diagram of the parts in the service manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tKgb.png).

---

### Sensor Tests

I also did several sensor tests using the normal sensor mode (not the latch mode).

##### Testing the Sensor for Papers in Tray (SR9)

Test of the cassette paper sensor (SR9):

- When I remove all papers in the paper tray, the display says "CAS 0".
- After I put papers back into the tray, the display says "CAS 1".

When the tray has papers, CAS = 1. When the tray has no paper, CAS = 0.

What I see: 0/tray has no paper, 1/tray has paper.
But page 224 (F14-14) of the manual says the exact opposite: "CAS: Cassette paper sensor (SR9): 0/Document presence, 1/Document absent".

##### Testing the Registration Sensor (SR11)

- When I did a sensor test after the paper jam, I saw "REG 1".
- After I removed the paper, I saw "REG 0".

What I see: 0/no paper, 1/has paper.
The manual says the exact opposite: "REG: Registration sensor (SR11): 0/Document presence, 1/Document absent"

##### Testing the Delivery Sensor (SR5)

- I ask the printer to make a copy. Before the printer completes the print, I open the left cover.
- Before I remove the half-printed document, the sensor test says "DEL 1 0".
- After I remove the half-printed document, the sensor test says: "DEL 0 0"
  What I see: 0 0/no paper, 1 0/has paper.
  The manual says the same thing: "Delivery sensor (SR5): 1/Document presence, 0/Document absence."

---

#### Retry Pickup?

On page 111, the service manual talks about a "Retry Pickup":

> - If the registration sensor(SR11) does not detect paper within a specific period of time after the cassette pickup roller has started
>   to rotate, the machine will start to rotate the cassette pickup roller
>   once again to execute a retry pickup operation
> - If the registration sensor (SR11) still does not detect paper within a specific period of time after executing a retry pickup 3 times, the
>   machine will identify the condition as a jam and will indicate a jam
>   message on the LCD of its control panel

At first, I thought maybe SR11 was faulty and couldn't detect the paper. That would make the machine do that "retry pickup".

But I am not sure because I *can't* even see an error code for the jam.

#### My attempt to get the error code for the jam

Does a jam always have an error code? If that is the case, how to see that code?

I have tried:

1. Go into maintenance mode (`[additional function]`, `[2]`, `[8]`, `[additional function]`)
2. Clear history of error
3. Copy something and let the paper jam.
4. Print the err log report.

But that history is blank.

---

#### Sensor flag problem?

This post talks about sensor flag problem in another printer: [HP Printer Jamming during Pick-up](https://superuser.com/questions/1343316/hp-printer-jamming-during-pick-up)

If the service manual's description of the sensor test is correct, maybe the sensor flags for SR9 and SR11 are misaligned.

However, when I don't put any paper in the tray, the printer would correctly ask me to load paper into the tray. This suggests the the cassette paper sensor (SR9) functions correctly. Yet, result of the sensor test of SR9 is the exact opposite of the service manual's description. Is the service manual wrong?

Knowing the jam code would really help to show which sensor/sensor flag have problem. Sadly, I can't get an error code.